# putting a view as subview of UIScrollView isn't putting at UIScrollView's content offset(0,0)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view 'a' which I am putting on scrollView.
The 'y' coordinate of 'a' is set to zero. And the scrollView dimensions are set accordingly, contentSize of scrollView is set to fit the view 'a'.

But still scrollview is shifting the view 'a' upwards.
What could be the reason?

Thank you,

Comment: I have this problem as well, and haven't been able to figure it out. It smells like a UIKit bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, here are a few things to check:

- What is the frame of the view `a`?  Verify that `a.frame.origin.y` is `0`.
- What are the bounds of the scrollView?  Verify that `scrollView.bounds.origin.y` is `0`.
- What is the size of the scrollView (`scrollView.bounds.size`)? This different is from its contentSize.  Is it large enough to fit `a` inside of it?

Comment: Yes, `a.frame.origin.y =0` and likewise `scrollview.bounds.origin.y = 0`. As I said I am setting the contentSize of the scrollview based on the dimensions of view, so it must be fitted..

Comment: As I said, `scrollView.bounds.size` is different from `scrollView.contentSize`.  Could you please check just to make sure that `scrollView.bounds.size` is large enough?  Also, what is the height of the subview, `a`?

Comment: Hey I am sorry, I was busy and I couldn't check it. even if the `scrollView.bounds` is less than `scrollView.contentSize`, it makes it scrollable. Is n't it?

Comment: Yes, but only within the bounds.  Are you able to scroll at all?